# Adding "manually" multiple React components in the same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm migrating an old "jQuery" application, adding some React components. I have some JS/jQuery code adding some elements in the DOM. I want to replace this using for example a new `Item` component, creating many instances and adding them to the same container. And I need to get the real DOM element to manipulate it (with the old JS/jQuery code).

I found this solution :

`const elt1 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ReactDOM.render(<CalendarItem item={item} />, container))`

but the container content is replaced with the new `Item` and adding many items, only the last is finally in the container.

I have tried `portal` :

`const elt2 = ReactDOM.createPortal(<CalendarItem item={item} />, container)`

but the returned element `elt2` is not a DOM element (that I can manipulate after).

Is there a solution to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: My approach would be to get rid of jQuery entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate React components using their related DOM elements, look into Refs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

So create the ref in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
  this.calendarItem = React.createRef();
}
```

And then give the ref to your new CalendarItem:

```
<CalendarItem item={item} ref={this.calendarItem} />
```

You can then access the actual DOM node of that CalendarItem using `this.calendarItem.current`, for example:

```
$(this.calendarItem.current).focus();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need to access to the DOM element from the component itself, but I need to "manually" create manu component in the same container, and get the DOM element for each component, outside this components, when I create this components.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand that explanation

Comment: If I'm right, your solution able a component to know its DOM element. It's not my need. I need to know the DOM element for a component "manually" added to a container (outside of this component)